# Countdown timer restart once starting another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, service, timer, countdown

I am new to android, I am trying to create multiple countdown timers in a list, within tabs. However, the countdown timer resets when I change tab, or start another intent. How can I make sure that the timer will never stop and prevent the timer to reset itself?

Here is my code:

```
public class OneFragment extends ListFragment {

View rootView;
TextView scheduleId;
ListAdapter listadapter;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final DBController controller = new DBController(getActivity());
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> scheduleList = controller.getAllSchedules();
    if (scheduleList.size()!=0){
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                scheduleId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleId);
                String getId = scheduleId.getText().toString();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getId, duration);
                toast.show();
                controller.deleteSchedule(getId);
                onResume();
            }
        });
        ArrayList schedule = new ArrayList();
        schedule.clear();
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM schedules";
        Cursor c1 = controller.selectQuery(query);
        if (c1 != null & c1.getCount() != 0) { //if there is item in the cursor
            if (c1.moveToFirst()) {  //start to move to position
                do {
                    getSchedule schedule1 = new getSchedule();  //create object of the class getParticipant
                    schedule1.setscheduleId(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("scheduleId")));  //set the friend id in the object
                    schedule1.setscheduleName(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("scheduleName")));  //set the friend name in the object
                    schedule1.setscheduleDuration(System.currentTimeMillis()+(60*Integer.parseInt(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("scheduleDuration")))*1000));
                    schedule.add(schedule1);  //add the object to arraylist
                } while (c1.moveToNext());  //if still have item in the cursor, loop again
            }
        }
        c1.close();
        CustomAdapter custom = new CustomAdapter(OneFragment.this, schedule);//create object of adapter class by
        //passing a context and arraylist
        setListAdapter(custom);  //set the adapter

    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {   //when user resume from an intent
    super.onResume();
    if (getListView() != null) {   //if the list view is not null
        updateData();     //call the method updateData() to update the listView
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

public void deleteData(String id){
    DBController controller = new DBController(getActivity());
    controller.deleteSchedule(id);
}

public void updateData(){
    final DBController controller = new DBController(getActivity());
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> scheduleList = controller.getAllSchedules();
    if (scheduleList.size()!=0){
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                scheduleId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleId);
                String getId = scheduleId.getText().toString();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getId, duration);
                toast.show();
                controller.deleteSchedule(getId);
                onResume();
            }
        });
        ArrayList schedule = new ArrayList();
        schedule.clear();
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM schedules";
        Cursor c1 = controller.selectQuery(query);
        if (c1 != null & c1.getCount() != 0) { //if there is item in the cursor
            if (c1.moveToFirst()) {  //start to move to position
                do {
                    getSchedule schedule1 = new getSchedule();  //create object of the class getParticipant
                    schedule1.setscheduleId(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("scheduleId")));  //set the friend id in the object
                    schedule1.setscheduleName(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("scheduleName")));  //set the friend name in the object
                    schedule1.setscheduleDuration(System.currentTimeMillis()+(60*Integer.parseInt(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("scheduleDuration")))*1000));
                    schedule.add(schedule1);  //add the object to arraylist
                } while (c1.moveToNext());  //if still have item in the cursor, loop again
            }
        }
        c1.close();
        CustomAdapter custom = new CustomAdapter(OneFragment.this, schedule);//create object of adapter class by
        //passing a context and arraylist
        setListAdapter(custom);  //set the adapter
    }
}
}

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<getSchedule> {

private LayoutInflater lf;
private List<ViewHolder> lstHolders;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lstHolders) {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (ViewHolder holder : lstHolders) {
                holder.updateTimeRemaining(currentTime);
            }
        }
    }
};

public CustomAdapter(OneFragment context, List<getSchedule> objects) {
    super(context.getActivity(), 0, objects);
    lf = LayoutInflater.from(context.getActivity());
    lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();
    startUpdateTimer();
}

private void startUpdateTimer() {
    Timer tmr = new Timer();
    tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = lf.inflate(R.layout.view_schedule_entry, parent, false);
        holder.tvProduct = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleName);
        holder.tvTimeRemaining = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleDuration);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        synchronized (lstHolders) {
            lstHolders.add(holder);
        }
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.setData(getItem(position));

    return convertView;
}
}

class ViewHolder {
TextView tvProduct;
TextView tvTimeRemaining;
String getid;
getSchedule mProduct;

public void setData(getSchedule item) {
    mProduct = item;
    tvProduct.setText(item.scheduleName);
    getid = item.getscheduleId();
    updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {
    long timeDiff = mProduct.getscheduleDuration() - currentTime;
    if (timeDiff > 0) {
        int seconds = (int) (timeDiff / 1000) % 60;
        int minutes = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
        int hours = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        tvTimeRemaining.setText(hours + " hrs " + minutes + " mins " + seconds + " sec");
    } else {

    }
}
}
```

I am stuck..Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can implemet an Runnable.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html

So you can do it like you said.